# Meta tag population

Tags: seo, search-engine

I would like know about changing the content of meta tags in keywords using javascript on each page, to make keywords different for each page. Is it good for the **SEO**  or not? Will **GOOGLE** be able to able to read the meta tag as i am changing the keywords with the help of javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Google no longer counts the meta keywords tags. They stopped doing so since somewhere near 2009.Here is the official link of the announcement.

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.gr/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html

You can check the article above from google support about what types of meta tags their bots are taking into consideration when they crawl your page.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en
On the other hand it is very good to have different pages for different keywords since only one of them is going to receive high ranking for a specific keyword.

But you have to do that without the meta keywords tags. You can use the title tags and the description tags also.You will can get some more by adding the keyword in the images alt text too. But yet again your meta keyword tags will have no value at all. So in my honest opinion try using the the methods i mentioned above and forget about managing the keywords with JavaScript.

If u have need more details feel free to ask in comments of my answer

Answer (score 0):

Google is on record saying they no longer look at this meta keywords tag. As for the meta description  and title tag, place text there that you think will optimize your click through rate on the SERPs, but don't cram keywords in.